# Entity splitting with EF Code First issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

So I am trying to achieve entity splitting in EF 6.1 with Code First, and I am running into an error.

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Organization]
(
    [OrganizationId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [TenantId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrganizationSettings]
(
    [OrganizationSettingsId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [OrganizationId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [AllowMultipleTimers] BIT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_OrganizationSettings_Organization] FOREIGN KEY (OrganizationId) REFERENCES Organization(OrganizationId)
)
```

With the following model objects:

```
public partial class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public OrganizationSettings Settings { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationSettings
{
    public int OrganizationSettingsId { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public bool AllowMultipleTimers { get; set; }
}
```

With the following config code:

```
        var org = modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>();
        org.Map(u =>
        {
            u.Properties(m => new { m.TenantId, m.Name });
        })
        .ToTable("Organization");

        org.Map(u =>
        {
            u.Property(m => m.Settings.AllowMultipleTimers).HasColumnName("AllowMultipleTimers");
            u.ToTable("OrganizationSettings");
        });
```

Then just the following query:

`context.Organizations.FirstOrDefault();`

Which yields the following error:

> The property 'Settings.AllowMultipleTimers' on type 'Organization'
>   cannot be mapped because it has been explicitly excluded from the
>   model or it is of a type not supported by the DbModelBuilderVersion
>   being used.

What am I doing wrong here?

*Update:* I forgot to mention that I created the database by hand, and am using the CF fluent API to map my models, rather than using "real" Code First.

Comment: do you use real code first? or have you created the tables in SQL and later added the ef models?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that, I created the tables by hand then used the fluent api

Comment: Isn't entity splitting using a single entity to represent multiple tables? Looks like you have an entity for each table?

Comment: Why are you mapping AllowMultipleTimers to a table?  AllowMultipleTimers is a bool not a Table.  You need to map your OrganizationSettings as its own entity, then map AllowMultipleTimes are a property of the OrganizationSettings entity, and the OrganizationSettings entity should be mapped to the table.

Comment: From a modeling perspective OrganizationSettings is not an entity, it is a value object that is part of the Organization entity. It is stored in a separate table as a technical detail. I am just trying to setup my EF mappings to match the model as closely as possible. In the end I may end up treating them as separate EF entities and just marrying them in my repository, but I am pretty sure I had this type of mapping working in the past, I just can't figure out why it's giving me that error now.

Answer (score 1):

While I was pretty sure I had this mapping working before, I went ahead and went a little different route.

First I got rid of the surrogate key on `OrganizationSettings (probably not strictly necessary), and then mapped it as an entity with a 1:1 relationship.

My OrganizationSettings is now:

```
public class OrganizationSettings
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public bool AllowMultipleTimers { get; set; }
}
```

OrganizationId is both a primary key and a foreign key.

And the config is:

```
        var org = modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>()
            .Map(u =>
            {
                u.Properties(m => new { m.TenantId, m.Name });
            })
            .HasRequired(m => m.Settings)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();


        modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationSettings>()
            .HasKey(m => m.OrganizationId);
```

And this seems to work just fine. Since I'm not exposing a `DbSet` for `OrganizationSettings` it keeps the conceptual modeling of `OrganizationSettings` as a value object intact.

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to set up `OrganizationSettings` as a complex type while using entity splitting as well? Something like this, perhaps:

```
public partial class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public OrganizationSettings Settings { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationSettings
{
    public bool AllowMultipleTimers { get; set; }
}
```

```
// if you don't have a key defined on OrganizationSettings, this might not be needed
modelBuilder.ComplexType<OrganizationSettings>();

modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>()
    .Map(u =>
    {
        u.Properties(m => new { m.OrganizationId, m.TenantId, m.Name });
        u.ToTable("Organization");
    })
    .Map(u =>
    {
        u.Properties(m => new { m.OrganizationId, m.Settings.AllowMultipleTimers });
        u.ToTable("OrganizationSettings");

        // If you wanted to set the key column name
        u.Property(m => m.OrganizationId).HasColumnName("OrganizationSettingsId");
    });
```